# Is hiding/showing divs the best practice in responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, user-experience

I am new to responsive design and I noticed that one way of implementing it is by hiding and showing divs depending on screen width. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 60em) {

    #desktop { visibility:hidden; }
    #mobile { visibility:visible; }
}

#desktop { visibility:visible; }
#mobile { visibility:hidden; }
```

Is this is considered "best practice" or is there a recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

In my sites, I would only do so if this did not involve double loading of assets such as different sized images, etc.  Sometimes hiding / showing divs is the only way to get a complex site to transform into a simple mobile site.  Another caution would be duplicating your navigational elements as Google will penalize for having too many links on a page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting out on responsive design, I highly recommend you take a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), and in particular their [responsive scaffolding](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).  Their break points are really helpful!

One thing Bootstrap provides directly out-of-the-box is CSS classes to show/hide elements based on the current viewport width.

That said, relying on show/hide for different viewports is - in my personal opinion - only really acceptable where totally necessary.

The key thing to remember is that in responsive development, you're developing for mobile devices as well which may, or may not, be on slow mobile network connections. It's important to optimise the markup as far as is possible to avoid unnecessary file-size.

Additionally, using show/hide inevitably means you've got a lot of repetition within your page which will cause problems with accessibility (screen-readers for example), and could end up with your site being penalised in the search engines.